# How to copy specific files from one directory to another in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, copy

I have a directory with a bunch of files that i need to copy to another directory , Using Java i would only like to copy the files that end with a ".txt" extension. I'm familiar with doing it for one file as shown below , please could you help me do this as a loop to see which files in the source directory match with a "txt" extension and then copy them all over to a new directory.

```
File sourceFileLocation = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\mike\\data\\assets.txt");

        File newFileLocation = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\mike\\destination\\newFile.txt");
        try {
            Files.copy(sourceFileLocation.toPath(), newFileLocation.toPath());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Mo, I think you will be satisfied with my answer.

Comment: @Mo, make sure you wrap the code in a _try-with-resources_ to avoid memory leaks. I will update my answer with this. So, check out the update.

Comment: Mo, answer has been updated. Make sure you use the updated solution in your work.

Comment: @Mo_01, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Files#list(Path)` to obtain a stream and use stream operations to filter and collect only those file names that contain the extension *txt*. For example:

```
List<Path> paths = Files.list(Paths.get("C:/Users/hecto/Documents")).filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
for (Path path : paths) {
    System.out.println(path.toString());
}
```

For me, this prints out:

```
C:\Users\hecto\Documents\file1.txt
C:\Users\hecto\Documents\file2.txt
C:\Users\hecto\Documents\file3.txt
```

Even though I have other files and folders in that directory
[image]

Using that, I came up with this solution to copy over those filtered files from their current location to a new destination and preserving the original names (Using Java 8 or above):

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("C:/Users/hecto/Documents"))) {
    List<Path> paths = stream.filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Path source : paths) {
        Path destination = Paths.get("C:/Users/hecto/Desktop/target" + File.separator + source.getFileName());
        Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }           
}
```

(Answer updated to use *try-with-resources* to close the stream)

Comment: @greg-449 good point! I should've shown that here.

Comment: @greg-449 I updated the answer.